# C++ program needs inputs from stdin, but I want to pipe/send these inputs from shell script

Tags: c++, shell, input, pipe, stdin

I have a C++ program and it reads various inputs from user (standard input) interactively and it works fine. But now I need to execute this program from a shell script (bash) and need to pass these inputs from this script only instead of passing from user manually.
My binary name is myprog and this what I have tried in the script.. but it is not working.

```
myprog << \
  __EOF__ | tail -n+21 | grep ":" >> logfile.log 2> /dev/null
   $bdy
   $bdm
   $bdd
   $bth
   $btm
   $bts
   $edy
   $edm
   $edd
   $eth
   $etm
   $ets
```

**EOF**

These variables contains some date and time, like year = 2014, month 01, hour = 04, minute = 59 and second = 20

Comment: We need more information about your problem. First of all, "it's not working" never gives you answers here because we don't know what's not working in particular. What does your program's input look like? What is your input, expected and actual output?

Comment: Thanks. Not working means it is not taking the inputs from script. In myprog I have set default values if the user does not give any input and just press ENTER. So with the command mentioned above myprog is taking default values only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your C++ program has nothing else to do then reading the data from stdin (or `cin` for C++).  It's your decision on the bash shell to create a temporary object with the data and pass it to the process that runs the executable that have been compiled from the C++ source.

Use a bash script like this

```
myprog << EOF | tail -n+21 | grep ":" >> logfile.log 2> /dev/null
foo
bar
EOF
```

Please note the exact macth between the end indicator in the last line and behind the `<<`.

Here a further example:

```
Harper@AMSEL ~/Documents
$ cat fff
cat << EOF -b | tail >> logfile.log 2>/dev/null
this text is used
these chars too
EOF

Harper@AMSEL ~/Documents
$ sh ./fff

Harper@AMSEL ~/Documents
$ cat logfile.log
     1  this text is used
     2  these chars too

Harper@AMSEL ~/Documents
```

You may have to check what arguments of you command is evaluated locally and what is used with the ssh at the remove machine. Probably the example above helps to isolate the problem from myprog.

Comment: I modified the command as per your inputs, but still it is not working. I tried something like this as I am trying to get the inputs from the server.

ssh servername myprog << EOF | tail -n+21 | grep ":" >> logfile.log 2> /dev/null
        foo
        bar
EOF

Comment: Yes, it helped me in isolating the issue.